# creating a count_letters function in c?

Tags: c, for-loop, count, cs50, c-strings

Task: Create a C code that gets some text input from the user and prints out a count of the number of letters in it. Letters can be any uppercase or lowercase alphabetic characters, but shouldn’t include any punctuation, digits, or other symbols.

- I have written this code but it prints the wrong output ( for example if input is "Ad" the output is "1 letter(s)" !) and I can't find the bug in it!
  Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char alphabets[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int length = strlen(text);
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (alphabets[j] == text[i] || toupper(alphabets[j]) == text[i])
            {
                m++;
            }
        }
        if (m == 0)
        {
            length--;
        }
        m = 0;
    }
    printf ("%i letter(s) \n", length);
    
}
```

Comment: Why can you not debug it?  Print out the m,n indices in the inner loop, to start with, do be sure that you are using valid indexing....(which you are not).

Comment: For future reference, 'prints the wrong output', with no detaiils of the inputs and outputs, will just get you downvoted/closed:(

Comment: You could save a lot of typing by replacing `char alphabets[] = {'a','b','c'...}` with ` char alphabets[] = "abcd...";

Comment: And you could save even more typing by generating the `alphabets` array on the fly with a `for` loop. Disclaimer: this won't work if the character encoding on your platform is [EBCDIC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code) which is very unlikely.

Comment: There are more bugs but... you can't have both loops going to `n`

Comment: Does the line `char alphabets[] = {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz};` compile ...??

Comment: @EugeneSh. char alphabets[] = "abcd..." doesn't compile.

Comment: It surely does.

Comment: @AbdeAe _"char alphabets[] = "abcd..." doesn't compile_: I don't believe you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `isalpha`

Then you can simply do:

```
int main (void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    size_t length = strlen(text);
    int n = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i])) ++n;
    }
    printf ("%i letter(s) \n", n);   
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks a lot. But I wonder how can I know all the functions that exist ?

Comment: Well, first step is to read a good "introduction to C" book. Thus a book will describe the standard function. Besides that there are many online sites available. But nothing beats experience... the more time you spend on writing programs and looking at others programs, the more you will learn. Don't expect to become a C expert in a few months :-)

Answer (score 2):

The nested for loops together with the variable `length` that is moreover used in this call

```
printf ("%i letter(s) \n", length);
```

do not make a sense.

Also this variable

```
int n = 0;
```

is unused.

And calling the standard function `strlen` is inefficient.

All you need is one for loop in which you will check whether a given character represents a letter.

Pay attention to that there is standard C function `isalpha` declared in the header `<ctype.h>` that determines whether a character is a letter.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main( void )
{
    string text = get_string( "Text: " );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( string current = text; *current != '\0'; ++current )
    {
        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )*current ) ) ++n;
    }

    printf( "%zu letter(s)\n", n );
}
```

Comment: Using `strlen` is no problem for this task. The program uses dynamic memory allocation and takes input from stdin. Those two things will take decades longer than `strlen`

Comment: @4386427 It is just a redundant call.

Comment: It doesn't matter. No reason to optimize for performance on something that doesn't impact the overall program behavior

Comment: @4386427 It can be reasonable if you are paid for the number of typed symbols.

Comment: @4386427 One of the most important principles in programming is making the code readable.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I started learning a week go so I don't recognize the size_t data type and the condition inside the if statement YET. I tried to solve that using the basics I have learned. thanks a lot!